# Catching MessageBox result

Tags: c#, messagebox, dialogresult

I'm trying to get the user to confirm if they want to delete a product using a MessageBox and catching its result. This is my code:

```
// Confirm if the user really wants to delete the product
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to delete the product \"" + productName + "\"?", "Confirm product deletion", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    MessageBox.Show("deleted");
}
```

When I run the code and try to delete a product, deleted never shows. On the MSDN page it says to use `MessageBoxResult` rather than `DialogResult` but Visual Studio doesn't recognise `MessageBoxResult`, and I use `DialogResult` elsewhere in my code for an open file dialog. Obviously, that's not the proper way to check it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must ask for `DialogResult.Yes`

```
// Confirm if the user really wants to delete the product
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to delete the product \"" +     productName + "\"?", "Confirm product deletion", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,  MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    MessageBox.Show("deleted");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the message box type set to yes/no, yet you are trying to catch an OK result. Catch the yes and you will be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the YesNo buttons, so the DialogResult.OK has nothing to do with it.
You should do

```
if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
```

for your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Just ask for the right DialogResult.

```
if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
```

Bear in mind, that a dialog can have different kind of results, and that you are also able to write your own results. Therefore: Have always a look on the result you are expecting and on the result you are checking.

Greetings,